# Postgres 10 sql How can I do distinct without all columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this following query that gets the closest cities/town to a certain coordinate that is passed in . It will return a max of 5 records and I only want to do a distinct on city and state . In the database I have some cities repeating if they are large so I would like to do a distinct on that and return a unique set of cities and state . Also some cities like Chicago for instance I have in the database 4 different times but the latitudes and longitude vary slightly that's why I must exclude latitudes and longitudes from the distinct query . .  When i run this query I get the following error

```
SELECT  distinct on(city::text || ', ' || state::text), latitudes, longitudes
FROM zips 
ORDER BY ABS(28.458414 - latitudes) + ABS(-81.395258-longitudes)
limit 5
```

> ERROR:  SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY
>   expressions LINE 1: SELECT  distinct on(city::text || ', ' ||
>   state::text)latitu...

I have also read but can't seem to get this to work

[Sql SELECT DISTINCT - How can I select distinct couple without considering columns' order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39276975/sql-select-distinct-how-can-i-select-distinct-couple-without-considering-colum)
but can't seem to get this working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's exactly as the error says. Your `ORDER BY` columns must match the `DISTINCT ON` columns initially, and you can put any other stuff to order by after that. So:

```
SELECT  distinct on(city::text || ', ' || state::text) latitudes, longitudes
FROM zips 
ORDER BY city::text || ', ' || state::text, ABS(28.458414 - latitudes) + ABS(-81.395258-longitudes)
limit 5
```

I don't see why you'd concatenate those fields though in the `DISTINCT ON`, it doesn't appear to serve any purpose since it will be as "unique" as specifying the columns individually, which would be more performant. So:

```
SELECT  distinct on(city, state) latitudes, longitudes
FROM zips 
ORDER BY city, state, ABS(28.458414 - latitudes) + ABS(-81.395258-longitudes)
limit 5
```

Bear in mind that specifying columns in `DISTINCT ON` does not return those columns, so your query currently would only return `latitudes, longitudes`, without any city or state info.

Answer (score 1):

The `Error` are clear.. And if you try to looking syntax first you should see documentation from `Postgresql`.. Because the information are detail.. This [`Documentation`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) and i take the quote from documentation :

> The “first row” of each set is unpredictable unless ORDER BY is used
>   to ensure that the desired row appears first

You need to put `ORDER BY` column you use in your `DISTINCT ON`. And @404 [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53620527/postgres-10-sql-how-can-i-do-distinct-without-all-columns/53620963#53620963) are great..